# How to put query params on _path rails_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

The problem is to pass Query params throuth the helper _path .

Example I know how to pass a normal param

```
edit_survey_path(@poll_module)
```

which generates

```
 /survey/12 because of route /survey/:id
```

Which is right and okay for editing

However, I want to generate the following url for new_survey_path

```
/survey/new?pollModule=lgpd
```

so how should I write the

```
new_survey_path(????)
```

At the view's controller I have the @poll_module = 'lgpd'

Then I trided

```
new_survey_path(@poll_module)
new_survey_path({@poll_module})
new_survey_path({pollModule: @poll_module})
new_survey_path({:pollModule => @poll_module)
new_survey_path(:pollModule, {pollModule: @poll_module})
```

yes some are crazy, but it were things I have found on foruns

```
 new_survey_path(@poll_module) generates 

 http://rubyenv:3000/surveys/new.lgpd?
```

that's because the route for edit is 
    #routes
    new_survey GET  /surveys/new(.:format) so is gets on the format

I want a query param 
    /surveys/new?pollModule=lgpd

because on the new survey I need to search the righ questions before answering the survey, and this question depende on the module

Comment: How did you define your `survey` routes in your `config/routes.rb`?

Answer (score 3):

Normally you pass a query param like this `new_survey_path({key: "value1", key2: "value2"})`. So the one version you have reported that you tried should have worked. Thats why i assume it could interfere with your routes. Can you try to isolate the problem and simply add the following to your project:

```rb
# routes.rb
resources :surveys, only: [:new]
```

```rb
# app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @pollModule = params[:pollModule]
  end
end
```

```html
<!-- app/views/surveys/new.html.erb -->
<h1>New Survey</h1>
<p>poll module inserted as query param: <%= @pollModule %></p>
<%= link_to "testLink", new_survey_path(pollModule: "randomInput")  %>
```

When you click on the "testLink" it should redirect you to the URL `localhost:3000/surveys/new?pollModule=randomInput`.

Also be sure that the route is at the top of your routes.rb file, since sometimes the ordering is what messes things up. Hope that helpes and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The problem it was not the _path helper, but the componet I was using on the view

if you use the button_to, it has already a parameter for parameters

{poll_module: 'teste123'} %>

doc ref -> 
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

or if i you use the link_to it get the query by default

doc -ref-> 
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to